# Unable to connect to SQL Server database from another machine

Tags: sql-server

I need to access a SQL Server database which is installed on one machine and I want to access it from another machine. I have tried below options and nothing work

1. I have enabled TCP\IP with IPALL as 1433 in SQL Server Configuration manager
2. SQL Server and SQL Server Browser services are running, restarted after modified the configuration
3. Added SQL Server and TCP port to Windows firewall (allowed apps) as domain and public

Used

```
sqlcmd -S servername,portname -U username -P password -d database
```

What am I missing? On my local machine, it is working

Comment: Did you try with Server **IP** instead of Server name ?

Comment: Did you enable NamePipe protocol? 

ref (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-ver15) ，browser service use UDP port 1434

Comment: sqlcmd -S serveripAddress,1433 -U username -P password -d database try this

Comment: I came to know that the server machine which has mysql which is installed has lot of restriction even though the port is opened. thanks for all your suggestion